# Как получить элемент строки html-кода с помощью bs4 (python)

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Есть строка html-кода

```
<li><a href="/catalog/1022/">Автоматы LCT UP</a></li>
```

допустим в переменной link. Из нее нужно получить ссылку (href). Видел метод link.get('href'), но у меня почему-то не работает, мб из-за разных версий чего-либо. Как можно это сделать, если что питон 3.9, бс4 последней версии

Весь код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml


req = requests.get('https://airsoft-rus.ru')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, features='lxml')
links = soup.findAll(class_='main-menu')
gun_links = links[0].find('ul')
for link in gun_links:
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://airsoft-rus.ru')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, features='lxml')
links = soup.find(class_='main-menu').findAll('li')
print(*[link.a.get('href') for link in links], sep='\n')

/catalog/1020/
/catalog/1025/
....
/markdown/
/available-again/
```